# Not able to delete characters of cc card, expiration and security code of input field in firefox

Tags: firefox, ember.js, handlebars.js

Working on a ember app. I have this form that takes in name, cc number, expiration and security number. I am able to backspace on name however I cant delete any of the other content, and this only happens in Firefox.

```
<div class="form-group cc-name input-row {{if nameValid 'has-success'}}">
  <label class="label label--sm">Name on Card</label>
  {{input type="text" value=name class="form-control"}}
</div>

<div class="form-group cc-number input-row {{if numberValid 'has-success'}}">
  <label for="cc-number" class="label label--sm">Credit Card Number</label>
  {{input-credit-card-number number=number class="form-control"}}
  <div class="card-type {{if type 'show' 'hide'}}">
    {{#if type}}
      {{inline-svg type class="icon icon--credit-card"}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-row input-row--inline">
  <div class="form-group cc-expiration input-col--50 {{if expirationValid 'has-success'}}">
    <label class="control-label label--sm">Expiration</label>
    {{input-credit-card-expiration month=month year=year class="form-control"}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group cc-cvc input-col--50 {{if cvcValid 'has-success'}}">
    <label class="control-label label--sm">Security Code</label>
    {{input-credit-card-cvc cvc=cvc class="form-control"}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I need to override:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import hasTextSelected from 'ember-credit-cards/utils/has-text-selected';
import formatters from 'ember-credit-cards/utils/formatters';
import cards from 'ember-credit-cards/utils/cards';

var cardFromNumber = cards.fromNumber;
var computed = Ember.computed;

function inputValid(value) {
  value = (value + '').replace(/\D/g, '');

  var card = cardFromNumber(value);

  if (card) {
    return value.length <= card.length[card.length.length - 1];
  } else {
    return value.length <= 16;
  }
}


export default Ember.TextField.extend({
 classNames: ['input-credit-card-number'],
 placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••',
 autocomplete: 'cc-number',
 type: 'tel',

 keyPress: function(e) {
   var digit = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   console.log(digit);
   if (!/^\d+$/.test(digit)) {
     return false;
   }

   var el = this.$();
   if (hasTextSelected(el)) {
     return true;
   }

   var value = el.val() + digit;
   return inputValid(value);
   console.log(value);
 },

 value: computed('number', function(key, value) {
   var number = this.get('number');

   if (arguments.length > 1) {
     number = value;
     this.set('number', value);
   }

    return formatters.formatNumber(number);
  })

});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `ES6`?

Comment: I installed v 0.04 on a new project locally and am having the same issue with the CVC component. I re-opened an issue on github for it [here](https://github.com/arenoir/ember-credit-cards/issues/3)

Comment: Awesome, hopefully someone will be able to help us out. If I find a solution I will definitively post it here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
 classNames: ['input-credit-card-number'],
 placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••',
 autocomplete: 'cc-number',
 type: 'tel',


keyPress: function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 13){
    return true;
  }

   var digit = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if (!/^\d+$/.test(digit)) {
     return false;
   }
      var el = this.$();
   if (hasTextSelected(el)) {
     return true;
   }

   var value = el.val() + digit;
   return inputValid(value);
   console.log(value);
 },

 value: computed('number', function(key, value) {
   var number = this.get('number');

   if (arguments.length > 1) {
     number = value;
     this.set('number', value);
   }

    return formatters.formatNumber(number);
  })

});
```